# Spring Integration DSL: Disable double DEBUG logging in AbstractMessageHandler

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm using the .log() function from Spring Integration DSL and I want to create a log at the DEBUG level. Here is an example:

```
...
.<DataDTO>log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, "Http Input Flow V2",          
              message -> {
                 DataDTO dto = message.getPayload();
                 return "Input data: " + dto.toString;
              })
...
```

This works, however, two logging messages are created: the actual logging message `Input data: ...` and the one from the `AbstractMessageHandler`:

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) {
    ...
    if (this.loggingEnabled && this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        this.logger.debug(this + " received message: " + message);
    }
    ...
 }
```

In `AbstractMessageHandler`, `this.loggingEnabled` is set to `true` by default.

Is it possible to disable the logging in the `AbstractMessageHandler` but keep the custom log message? I've tried to set the logging level for the `AbstractMessageHandler` in my `application.yml` to `ERROR`, but this did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have in your logging config something like `org.springframework.integration=DEBUG` or even `org.springframework=DEBUG`.

The literal `"Http Input Flow V2"` is a bit awkward for the category:

```
   /**
     * Populate a {@link WireTap} for the {@link #currentMessageChannel}
     * with the {@link LoggingHandler} subscriber for the provided
     * {@link LoggingHandler.Level} logging level, logging category
     * and {@link Function} for the log message.
     * @param level the {@link LoggingHandler.Level}.
     * @param category the logging category.
     * @param function the function to evaluate logger message at runtime
     * @param <P> the expected payload type.
     * against the request {@link Message}.
     * @return the current {@link IntegrationFlowDefinition}.
     * @see #wireTap(WireTapSpec)
     */
    public <P> B log(LoggingHandler.Level level, String category, Function<Message<P>, Object> function) {
```

Also that `loggingEnabled` can be disabled by the `@EnableIntegrationManagement` and its:

```
/**
 * Use to disable all logging in the main message flow in framework components. When 'false', such logging will be
 * skipped, regardless of logging level. When 'true', the logging is controlled as normal by the logging
 * subsystem log level configuration.
 * <p>
 * It has been found that in high-volume messaging environments, calls to methods such as
 * {@code logger.isDebuggingEnabled()} can be quite expensive and account for an inordinate amount of CPU
 * time.
 * <p>
 * Set this to false to disable logging by default in all framework components that implement
 * {@link IntegrationManagement} (channels, message handlers etc). This turns off logging such as
 * "PreSend on channel", "Received message" etc.
 * <p>
 * After the context is initialized, individual components can have their setting changed by invoking
 * {@link IntegrationManagement#setLoggingEnabled(boolean)}.
 * @return the value; true by default.
 */
String defaultLoggingEnabled() default "true";
```

To `false`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#_configuring_metrics_capture

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by category. Usually I give my loggern the name of the class. Do you have examples for better categories?

Comment: Correct. In most cases it is class name or just package. But anyway any possible string can be a name for the logging category. For example `root` is there. For your use case I would do in the `application.yml`: `logging.level.Http_Input_Flow_V2=DEBUG`. The same string what you have but without whitespaces. Then you will have DEBUG messages in logs only for this part of your application.